# Play Different MediaSource Together in Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am stuck to playing parallel diffrent Media streams in Exoplayer

Scenario:

- I have one Audio MediaSource. and one Video MediaSource.
- I want to play that both mediasource Parallelly in `ExoPlayer`

After lots of R&D i found

- https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1828
- https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4793

I am trying but failed to achive that. 
code of Example here

```
if (player == null) {
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ChangeAudioActivity.this, new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
    player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
}

MediaSource audiosource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new FileDataSourceFactory()).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoModel.getAudio()));
MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new FileDataSourceFactory()).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoModel.getVideo()));
player.prepare(new MergingMediaSource(videoSource , audiosource ), true, false);
```

I refer Exoplayer Docs also.

- https://exoplayer.dev/media-sources.html

Is that Possible with Exoplayer? Thank you in Advance for Your Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**This is an issue of Exoplayer But My Point of View its not an Issue because ExoPlayer was think with sense means....**

- If Already Your Video Has Audio so Why Second Audio you want to play ? so your input audio not add or play in exoplayer.
- But you input Video Without Audio And also input Second Audio In Function So it's Work definitely.

**I understand! you want to mix dual audio play with your video in exoPlayer but It not possible without any Editing**

Comment: Thanks Sanjay for describing issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use two instances of Exoplayer, one for the video, one for the audio.

Comment: two instances is bad practice!

Comment: Why would it be bad practice? Imagine you need to implement a piano app. I'd create and cache for each key an ExoPlayer instance in memory, with the corresponding audio sample mp3 asset for each note. How would you implement this?